# Putting a submitted question on hold

Tags: support

I had written a question and submitted it. Shortly thereafter, I felt I wanted to make some substantial changes. In that I didn't have time, I copied the text and emailed it to myself for later use and deleted the question, especially so as not to elicit any responses until I felt the question was complete.

Is there any way to temporarily "hide" a question for further revision and submission.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete it. Later, if you save the URL, you can undelete it. If you don't have the URL, you can ask a moderator to find it or undelete it for you. I don't think there is another way to "hide" a question. Of course, the latter relies on the kindness of the moderators. :-)

Comment: To add to this, keep a note of the URL of the question, before deletion, so that anyone involved can find it without extra effort.

Comment: @WillJagy: good idea. However, a mod can search for, and see the deleted posts in your profile. If it is recent, there shouldn't be much extra effort.

Comment: I may be mistaken about 10K or 20K users being able to see their self-deleted questions or answers in their profile.

Comment: Neither 10K nor 20K see self-deleted posts in their profiles. The only way to access a deleted post for such users is to have the URL.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: yes; I just asked some 20K users on chat, and this is verified. Thanks.